# QFuture signal is emitted in wrong times

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, qt

I'm trying to use QT's QFuture and QFutureWatcher to implement a worker thread with notifications, but the notification is not coming at the correct time!

I'm calling `loadFile(QString)` from a menu handler, and expect the load to happen in a worker thread, and that's what happens. But `ibLoadFinished()` is getting called right after doing the `connect`, and not after exiting 
`LoadFromDisk()`. (The disk access is done in the IBF constructor).

What am I doing wrong?

ImageViewer.h:

```
class ImageViewer : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  static IBF* LoadFromDisk(const QString& filename);

private:
  QFuture<IBF*> ibfLoadedFuture;
  QFutureWatcher<IBF*> ibfLoadedFutureWatcher;

private slots:
  //...
  Q_SLOT void ibLoadFinished();
}
```

ImageViewer.cpp:

```
ImageViewer::ImageViewer() : ibfLoadedFutureWatcher(this)
{
  // ...
  connect(&ibfLoadedFutureWatcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(ibLoadFinished()));
  ibfLoadedFutureWatcher.setFuture(ibfLoadedFuture);
  //...
}

bool ImageViewer::loadFile(const QString& filename)
{
  if (ibfLoadedFuture.isRunning())
    return false;
  ibfLoadedFuture = QtConcurrent::run(LoadFromDisk, filename);
  return true;
}

IBF* ImageViewer::LoadFromDisk(const QString &filename)
{
  IBF* ibf = new IBF(filename);
  return ibf;
}

void ImageViewer::ibLoadFinished()
{    
  IBF* ibf(ibfLoadedFuture);
  process(*ibf);
  delete ibf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not explicitly stated in the documentation, `QFutureWatcher::setFuture` must be called whenever you get a new `QFuture` from `QtConcurrent::run()`, which means you can't call `setFuture` in the constructor for `ImageViewer` as you have done.  Also, it shouldn't be necessary to keep the `QFuture` as a member of your class since `QFutureWatcher` provides the means to determine if the concurrent task is still running.

In summary, remove this line from the constructor:
`ibfLoadedFutureWatcher.setFuture(ibfLoadedFuture);`

Then change your implementation of `loadFile` to the following:

```
bool ImageViewer::loadFile(const QString& filename)
{
  if (ibfLoadedFutureWatcher.isRunning())
    return false;
  QFuture<IBF*> ibfLoadedFuture = QtConcurrent::run(LoadFromDisk, filename);
  ibfLoadFutureWatcher.setFuture(ibfLoadedFuture);
  return true;
}
```

Also, you can get the result from the concurrent run by using `QFutureWatcher::result()`:

```
void ImageViewer::ibLoadFinished()
{    
  IBF* ibf = ibfLoadedFutureWatcher.result();
  process(*ibf);
  delete ibf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's now working.
How did you figure it out? I wasn't able to find any code example with that order of calls.